# Unwrap Rails POST params hash and map to model attributes w/ strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, strong-parameters

I am building a rails4 api where i am posting a nested hash of attributes. however, the model does not actually have nested attributes or an association. Attempting to make a cleaner post params hash by combining some attributes into a group, but have the api handle the unwrapping and strong parameters validation.

```
## Example POST params
params[:item][:group] = {
  a: true,
  b: false
}
```

But the model does not actually have a `group` column, the attributes `a` and `b` are attributes directly on the model.

to handle this without the `group` wrapper would simply be

```
params.require(:item).permit(:a, :b)
```

But I would like to have it pass `strong_parameters` submitted with the `group` wrapper. How can I achieve this but having the POST params as mentioned above?

Comment: i ended up making the group a single hstore column and permitting each hash key individually instead of each attribute be its own column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like most ruby/rails situations there's likely a better way of doing this. grabbing from the responses i end up with this seemingly hack approach. the important thing is that it does what i'm looking for, but it feels icky so if someone has a more elegant way please share!

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

private

  ## POST { item: { group: { a: true, b: false } } }
  def item_params
    group = params[:item][:group].presence

    if group
      ## Unwrap nesting and place at root of params[:item]
      ## Probably should explicitly handle this instead of iterating
      group.each {|k,v| params[:item][k] = v }
      params[:item].delete :group
    end

    params[:item].permit(:a, :b)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could strip all intermediate levels before your call the action:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_action :flatten_item_params

  private

  def flatten_item_params
    params[:item] = params.require(:item).each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
      result.merge!(value)
    end
  end

  def item_params
    params[:item].permit(:a, :b)
  end
end
```

Comment: i did, but it will result in an unknown attributes error when it hits the controller action.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: Ah sorry, so your question mentioned that `:group` is not an attribute of the model, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In regards the passing of "nested" parameters, the [docs are pretty explicit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit); as `Hoang Phan` recommended, you can pass a *nested* hash to your controller:

```
params: {
   object: {
      title: "Test",
      group: {
         a: "test", 
         b: "test"
      }
   }
}
```

This can be accepted with:

```
def params
   params.require(:object).permit(:title, group: [:a, :b])
end
```

--

The **problem** with this is that I believe all keys have to be present in the model. To remedy this, you can use a [`virtual attribute`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xuuJRj6DVU):

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :group, :a, :b
end
```

Virtual attributes are not saved, but are *instance* methods appended to the class, allowing you to populate it with data which you don't need to put into the database.

Using the above *should* give you the ability to use the nested params hash; the only downside would be that you have to stick to `group: [:a, :b]` as a structure for your params.